# Problem with Automator/AppleScript Question

Tags: applescript, automator

I am building a program to delete files/folders. Here is how my program looks in Automator:

[image]

The problem I am having is sometimes where the program runs I get this error:

[image]

The program does work so I don't know why this error is popping up. Is there an Automator or AppleScript command that I can use to bypass this error so it does not show up at all?

[image]

This is the AppleScript:

```
delay 5
tell application "Finder"
    try
        delete (every item of folder "TV Show Downloads" of disk "Drobo" whose modification date is less than ((get current date) - 1 * days))
    end try
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you may be getting this error because you are trashing folders and files in the same action. In other words, if automator tossed out a folder containing a '.mov' file, it will toss out the '.mov' file as well; then (later) when automator tries to toss that '.mov' file, it cannot find it, because it's already in the trash.

First solution to try: move the `kind is folder` option to the bottom of the list, in the hopes it sorts folders last.

If that doesn't work, then you may need to complexify your workflow with a variable, like so:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A common Automator error is to just get items, forgetting to remove an action added for testing, or that an application or service can already have items passed to the workflow.  This can result in extra or duplicate input items - for example a **Filter Finder Items** action will apply the filters to the *current* workflow items, while a **Find Finder Items** will apply the filters to items from the specified source, *adding* them to the workflow items.

Your error is most likely from doubling up some of the file references.  The application will already get items passed to it automatically (the items dropped onto it), and those are being added to the items returned from the **Find Finder Items** action, resulting in the workflow trying to trash items that have already been moved to the trash.

Automator doesn't have any control or conditional actions, so if you are running an application without the intention of dropping items onto it, each action has an `Ignore Input` option that will prevent the usage of any items passed to it.  By using this option on the initial **Find Finder Items** action, you won't have to worry about anything extra being added from dropping items onto the application.

If what you are wanting to do is make sure you haven't accidentally grouped something in with the items you are wanting to trash, using the **Filter Finder Items** action instead of **Find Finder Items** will perform the filters on the items passed to the workflow without getting any others.

Comment: In Automator below "Find Finder Items" if I add "Filter Finder Items" below that will that get rid of the error?

Comment: Replace the **Find Finder Items** action with **Filter Finder Items** - the find action adds more items to the workflow.  I've clarified my answer.

Comment: I have done what you said to do and now when I run the app it doesn't do anything. Any suggestions?

Comment: The filter action would apply the specified filters to items dropped onto the application.

Comment: I have added a picture to my question of what I have now in automator. Is it correct?

Comment: According to that last screenshot, there is still a **Find Finder Items** action in the workflow, although I don't see it.  You can also look at the results from each action to see the items returned.

Comment: I have added a new screenshot to the bottom of the answer. Is that correct?

Comment: That should do it, although you will need to drop the items you want to use onto the application.

Comment: I could possibly do that (AppleScript can also be used in an Automator workflow), but SO isn't really an application writing service.  You can also edit your topic to include more specific details about what you are wanting to do, or start a different one.

Comment: If I wanted to build an AppleScript to do this instead of an application do you know how to help me with that? I already have an AppleScript with this code (AppleScript code at the top in the question.) but only delete things that are a day old and I don't want that. I want it to delete everything in the folder regardless of when it was made, also the script only deletes files and not folders. I want it to delete folders as well.

Comment: I think I made an AppleScript that will work. Thank you so much for your help.